# Поймать свайп на JS

Tags: jquery

Есть объект `<div>`. Как поймать действие на мобильных устройствах, когда объект тянут вверх или вниз?

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, то обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под счетчиком голосов ответа

Comment: Раз уж у вас в тегах jQuery,.. то что вам мешает воспользоваться готовым решением https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin  Когда-то я сам его использовал для одного проекта. Пожалуй лучшее расширение на эту тему.

Answer (score 0):

Зарегистрируйте обработчик на touchstart и touchmove события.

Посмотрите информацию [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43232508/9921853) - там многое описано.